# Create a matrix combining many variables by using their names and a for loop

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have n .mat files and each are named as follows: `a1, a2, ..., an`

And within each of these mat files there is a variable called: `var` (nxn matrix)

I would like to create a matrix: `A = [a1.var a2.var, ..., an.var]` without writing it all out because there are many .mat files

A for-loop comes to mind, something like this:

```
A = []
for i = 1:n 
    [B] = ['a',num2str(i),'.mat',var];
     A = [A B]
end
```

but this doesn't seem to work or even for the most simple case where I have variables that aren't stored as a(i) but rather 'a1', 'a2' etc.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't you need `load` command to load variables from the mat files?

Comment: yes sorry forgot to write that

Comment: Just edited my code that uses `pre-allocation` for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*load and concatenate 'var' from each of 'a(#).mat':*

```
n = 10;
for i = n:-1:1                       % 1
    file_i = sprintf('a%d.mat', i);  % 2
    t = load(file_i, 'var');
    varsCell{i} = t.var;             % 3
end
A = [varsCell{:}];  % concatenate each 'var' in one step.
```

Here are some comment on the above code. All the memory-related stuff isn't very important here, but it's good to keep in mind during larger projects.

**1)**
In MATLAB, it is rarely a good idea or necessary to grow variables during a for loop. Each time an element is added, MATLAB must find and allocate a new block of RAM. This can really slow things down, especially for long loops or large variables. When possible, pre-allocate your variables (`A = zeros(n,n*n)`). Alternatively, it sometimes works to count backwards in the loop. MATLAB pre-allocates the whole array, since you're effectively telling it the final size.

**2)**
Equivalent to `file_i = ['a',num2str(i),'.mat']` in this case, `sprintf` can be clearer and more powerful.

**3)**
Store each 'var' in a cell array. This is a balance between allocating all the needed memory and the complication of indexing into the correct places of a preallocated array. Internally, the cell array is a list of pointers to the location of each loaded 'var' matrix.

---

*to create a test set...*
generate 'n' matrices of n*n random doubles
save each as 'a(#).mat' in current directory

```
for i = 1:n
    var = rand(n);
    save(sprintf('a%d.mat',i), 'var');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
%%// The final result, A would have size nX(nXn)
A = zeros(n,n*n); %%// Pre-allocation for better performance
for k =1:n
    load(strcat('a',num2str(k),'.mat'))
    A(1:n,(k-1)*n+1:(k-1)*n+n) = var;
end
```